# How many computers can I connect simultaneously using Android tethering?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, tethering

Yesterday I tried to connect 5 computers with my Android smartphone to the internet, however, I could only connect two of them simultaneously, is this the theorical limitation or there is any configuration to be done to increase this number? Is this a limitation of my smartphone's wifi card?

PS: Android 2.2 @ Samsung Galaxy 551

Comment: did you receive IP addresses from android for all of them?

Comment: yes, I mean, for the 2 that i could connect simultaneously.

Comment: again. Connected to internet via android phone only 2 of them but all of them wifi connected to the android hostspot without any problems receiving their IP addresses correspondingly? Could be the the issue of the particular samsung galaxy 551 AFAK they create their own brews of android. Here's an issue about 8-client AP limit for galaxy S http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/issues/detail?id=1171

Comment: I didnt noticed about DHCP or ip adresses, when I connect the 3th computer, the first one that was connected just goes disconect state..

Comment: looks like obvious dhcp /31 restriction to me...

Comment: Sorry, but it is not obvious for me and for most of users here, what "dhcp /31" means? Could you give us details? Please consider to post it as an answear..

Comment: If your devices are getting disconnected from AP's wifi when you try to connect them it means that AP's DHCP does not  lease more than 2 addresses meaning subnet /31 and the rest is disconnected. Have you checked the DHCP of all devices?? What do they get? If they are connected to the AP but not connected to the internet it means it's a firewall/nat restriction.

Comment: As far as I've read, there is a limit on how many devices can simultaneously connect to an Android-device-hotspot; if I remember correctly, it was 5 clients. But at the moment I cannot find the source where I read it...